# Javascript not breaking

Tags: javascript, html, break

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
      switch (listindex) {
        case "elections":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("YOUNG", "Young");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("FREEMAN", "Freeman");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("BRAY", "Bray");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[4] = new Option("GROOMS", "Groom");
          break;
        case "veterans":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("BREAUX", "Breaux");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("TAYLOR", "Taylor");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("SANDLIN", "Sandlin");
          break;

        case "health":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("BREAUX", "Breaux");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("TAYLOR", "Taylor");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("SANDLIN", "Sandlin");
          break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<title>Senator Drop Down List</title>

<body>
  <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
    <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Committee</option>
        <option value="elections">ELECTIONS</option>
        <option value="veterans">VETERANS</option>
         <option value="health">HEALTH</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Senator:
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
      document.write('<select name="senator" id="senator"><option value="">Select senator</option></select>')
    </script>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

My problem with this is that each case is not breaking and starting over the value of the option number. For example, it will go 1,2,3 from the election drop down box, but will continue to 4 as well for the next dropdown box and doesn't break. Thank you!

Comment: @DarrenSweeney sorry, first time of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear the `options` especially the `options[4]` value like `document.getElementById("senator").options = null;`. Otherwise the old options still remain when you dont override them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to clear the contents of the dynamic drop down every time you call the function. Otherwise, it will only write over the elements that you are adding. Since your first list is longer, the other lists will never overwrite that extra element.

Add `document.getElementById("senator").innerHTML = '';` just after defining `function dynamicdropdown()`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
      document.getElementById("senator").innerHTML = '';
      switch (listindex) {
        case "elections":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("YOUNG", "Young");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("FREEMAN", "Freeman");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("BRAY", "Bray");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[4] = new Option("GROOMS", "Groom");
          break;
        case "veterans":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("BREAUX", "Breaux");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("TAYLOR", "Taylor");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("SANDLIN", "Sandlin");
          break;

        case "health":
          document.getElementById("senator").options[0] = new Option("Select Senator", "");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[1] = new Option("BREAUX", "Breaux");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[2] = new Option("TAYLOR", "Taylor");
          document.getElementById("senator").options[3] = new Option("SANDLIN", "Sandlin");
          break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<title>Senator Drop Down List</title>

<body>
  <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
    <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Committee</option>
        <option value="elections">ELECTIONS</option>
        <option value="veterans">VETERANS</option>
         <option value="health">HEALTH</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Senator:
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
      document.write('<select name="senator" id="senator"><option value="">Select senator</option></select>')
    </script>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting all the options in different `<optgroup>`s, each having a class that matches the "committee" options:

```
<select name="senator" id="senator">
  <option value="">Select senator</option>
  <optgroup class="elections">
    <option value="Young">YOUNG</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="veterans">
    <option value="Breaux">BREAUX</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="health">
    <option value="Breaux">BREAUX</option>
    ...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You could hide all `<optgroup>`s by default, then display them based on whether their parent `<select>` has their class:

**CSS:**

```
optgroup {
  display: none;
}

select.elections optgroup.elections,
select.veterans optgroup.veterans,
select.health optgroup.health {
  display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
  document.getElementById('senator').className = listindex;
}
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
function dynamicdropdown(listindex) {
  document.getElementById('senator').className = listindex;
}
```

```css
optgroup {
  display: none;
}

select.elections optgroup.elections,
select.veterans optgroup.veterans,
select.health optgroup.health {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_div" id="category_div">Committee:
  <select id="committee" name="committee" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select Committee</option>
        <option value="elections">ELECTIONS</option>
        <option value="veterans">VETERANS</option>
         <option value="health">HEALTH</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">
  Senator:
  <select name="senator" id="senator">
    <option value="">Select senator</option>
    <optgroup class="elections">
      <option value="Young">YOUNG</option>
      <option value="Freeman">FREEMAN</option>
      <option value="Bray">BRAY</option>
      <option value="Grooms">GROOMS</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="veterans">
      <option value="Breaux">BREAUX</option>
      <option value="Taylor">TAYLOR</option>
      <option value="Sandlin">SANDLIN</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup class="health">
      <option value="Breaux">BREAUX</option>
      <option value="Taylor">TAYLOR</option>
      <option value="Sandlin">SANDLIN</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a better option especially if you want to do something with the selections afterwards. You can then get the values of the selections to run some other js functions afterwards.